# Unable to pass data variable from Ionic/Angular to Laravel via ajax

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, laravel, ionic-framework

I'm using Laravel 5.2 as backend API for my Ionic App. I'm facing this weird error when posting data from ionic(angular) to Laravel via ajax($http)

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access`

The problem comes only when i'm passing some data object. Otherwise ajax is working fine.

For interaction between Ionic and Laravel, i've created a middleware `cors`, registered it in `Kernel` and applied on `Route` group.

Middleware `Cors.php`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin');
}
```

Kernel

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
```

Routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'cors'], function(){
    ...
});
```

But it doesn't work. To my surprise, if i put headers directly to `public/index.php` file, the problem is solved.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
```

I don't think it's a good practise to put it directly in index.php`. So, what am i missing?

Comment: angular wont know your backend php is using laravel framework, but the php page ur requesting from angularjs should be included those headers